# How to maintain diffrent debug and production project in Android

Tags: android, firebase, github

What could be the best structure of any android project so that we can separate the release and debug version? We can test debug and move it easily in the release version.

We are using the following SDKs that can impact on your answers,
1. Github
2. Firebase
3. Admob
4. Facebook audience network SDK

How to share the release and debug project in Firebase and sync whenever it is required?
How to share debug and release projects in Github and sync whenever it is required?

Answer (score -1):

To prepare your application for release, you need to configure, build, and test a release version of your application. The configuration tasks are straightforward, involving basic code cleanup and code modification tasks that help optimize your application.
And for debug to deactivate logging and disable the debugging option before you build your application for release. You can deactivate logging by removing calls to Log methods in your source files. You can disable debugging by removing the android: debuggable attribute from the  tag in your manifest file, or by setting the android: debuggable attribute to false in your manifest file. Also, remove any log files or static test files that were created in your project.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, How to share the release and debug project in Firebase and sync whenever it is required?